Show EAN number on Woocommerce variable product
I need a update solution for variations products.
i managed to add a EAN number to a single product in Woocommerce.
This is working on single products because they don't change values.
When i make a selection on a variable product the content on the page does not change.
The content is from an custom_field named _global_unique_id.
I really don't know how to change the text on a different selection.
If have this in my child theme functions.php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'production_time2', 11 );
function production_time2() {
    global $product;
    $production_time = $product->get_meta( '_global_unique_id' );
    if ( ! empty($production_time) ) {
        echo '<p class="sku_wrapper">' . sprintf( __( ' EAN Barcode: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $production_time ) . '</p>';
    }
}


Try this: You need to include your custom field (_global_unique_id) in the variation data that WooCommerce sends to the front end. You can do this by using the woocommerce_available_variation filter.
// Add the EAN code to the variation data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_ean_code_to_variation_data' );
function add_ean_code_to_variation_data( $variation_data ) {
    $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_data['variation_id'] );
    $ean_code = $variation->get_meta( '_global_unique_id' );
    $variation_data['ean_code'] = $ean_code ? $ean_code : '';
    return $variation_data;
}

I have checked it on my personal page and it works.
You will have to adjust/change production_time2 in the HTML to include a placeholder where the EAN code will be displayed.
Example:
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'production_time2', 11 );
function production_time2() {
    global $product;
    $ean_code = $product->get_meta( '_global_unique_id' );
    echo '<p class="sku_wrapper ean_code_wrapper">';
    echo '<span class="ean_label">' . __( 'EAN Barcode:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span> ';
    echo '<span class="ean_code">';
    echo $ean_code ? $ean_code : '&nbsp;';
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</p>';
}

After you will have to take the EAN code in your jQUERY.
Test it and let me know if it worked for you aswell.

Thanks for your help. I is not working. It is showing the _global_unique_id from the main EAN field. and not from the selected field. the value does not change?  how do i add it to my jquery?

Do you use it in functions.php?
